# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, fingerprint

I try to use a piece of code on github, the whole project https://github.com/rtshadow/biometrics 
I used

```
python thining.py image.gif --save
```

But it has an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "thining.py", line 77, in <module>
make_thin(im)
File "thining.py", line 59, in make_thin
utils.load_pixels(im, loaded)
File "---/Github/biometrics/utils.py", line 111, in load_pixels
im_load[i, j] = pixels[i][j]
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The corresponding part of utiles.py is here:

```
 def load_pixels(im, pixels):
  (x, y) = im.size
  im_load = im.load()

  for i in range(0, x):
      for j in range(0, y):
          im_load[i, j] = pixels[i][j] // line 111
```

I don't know how to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try im_load[(i, j)] = pixels[i][j]?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right version of Python? What do you get when you do `python -v`?

Comment: @kabanus Yes I did. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @B.Eckles The README file says it's python 2.7. My version is 2.7.10.

Comment: @YULiu What is pixels? What do you get if you do `help(pixels)`? What about `help(pixels[0])`? Perhaps the error is coming from indexing into these objects instead of into `im_load`...

Comment: @B.Eckles I think it's the version problem. Seems python 2.7.10 is different from python 2.7.6, cuz I tried it on another machine with python 2.7.6 it works. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @YULiu Great! I posted that as an answer then which you can accept. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Python version: `python -v`. It seems it works with 2.7.6, but not 2.7.10. (See comments on original post.)